# $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{4n^2-i^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

How to calculate the following limit?

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{4n^2-i^2}}$

I think it should be a definite integral, but what's the function to integrate and over what interval?

Comment: are you sure it's not $i^2$?

Comment: @Alex It was a typo, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint: factor out $\frac{2}{\sqrt{4 n^2 - k}} = \frac{1}{n\sqrt{1 - (\frac{k}{2n})^2}}$ you get Riemann's integral

Comment: May I ask you about this one? I don't think it's worth asking a new question.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2^{i\over n}}{n+\frac{1}{i}}$$

I think it results to $\int_0^12^xdx$, but I don't know how. How was the interval $\langle0,1\rangle $ determined? What kind of subdivision was used? Thanks...

Comment: are you sure the denominator is $n + \frac{1}{k}$? If it were $n+k$ it would converge to $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2^x dx}{1+x}$ and then you can solve it by expanding $\frac{1}{1+x}$ in Geometric series

Comment: Yes, I am sure. That's how the problem is stated...

Comment: I'm not getting a simple solution unfortunately. Expand the denominator as $\frac{1}{n(1+\frac{1}{kn})} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{kn})^m$. To get $\int_{0}^{1} 2^x$ out of here is if every other term except $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n} 2^{\frac{k}{n}}$ converge to 0, which is quite possible.